# Drag & Drop Fullcalendar.io Resources - update view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I want do edit the nesting of fullcalendar.io Resources with drag & drop. Is there any posibility to do so. 
My approach:

```
 resourceRender: function(resource, cellEls) {
    cellEls.draggable({ handle: ".icon-resize-vertical", 
            revert: true, 
            helper: "clone",
            zIndex: 999,
            snap: true,
            opacity: 0.7
    });
    cellEls.droppable({
            hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( this ).css( "font-weight", "bolder" );
                    var childid = $(ui.draggable).closest("tr").attr("data-resource-id");
                    var childEl = $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'getResourceById', childid );
                    var parentid = $( this ).closest("tr").attr("data-resource-id");
                    var parentEl = $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'getResourceById', parentid );

                    childEl.parent = parentEl;
                    parentEl.children.push(childEl);
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');

            }
    });                         
},
```

The resource-objects show correct children and parent, but the calendar does not rerender.

Comment: another problem with my solution: I get a "circular structure to JSON", because of  childEl.parent = parentEl;
                    parentEl.children.push(childEl);

Answer (score 0):

If you destroy the calendar, your changes will be lost.

At the end of drag&drop, call

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```